# Why is IsNewRow property always returning false?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView, called `IncTbl`. I am looping over it, and I am adding the value of what is in column 4, index i to the `yearSalary` variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < IncTbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (IncTbl.CurrentRow.IsNewRow) break;
    yearSalary += (decimal)IncTbl[4, i].Value;
}
```

I do not want to add null, because I will get a `NullReferenceException`, so I am using `IsNewRow` property. However, it is returning false even when it is a new row. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "It", in your case is always `CurrentRow`, _not_ the row you are wanting...try `if (IncTbl.Rows[i].IsNewRow) break;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not the only person who has seen this sort of behavior.  It appears the `IsNewRow` has been reported as buggy in [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9c2b89d-10d2-45fa-a1d1-4cfbbef1916b/datagridviewcurrentrowisnewrow-is-not-working?forum=vbgeneral).

Incidentaly `break` is a bit unusual in this context.  You might consider slightly adjusting your loop as follows:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < IncTbl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!IncTbl.CurrentRow.IsNewRow)
              yearSalary += (decimal)IncTbl[4,i].Value;
        }
```

Comment: Also, to pid's answer below:  are you sure you know the *semantics* of IsNewRow?  Even if it's not buggy, you need to know that it means "this row has been added by the user in the UI after the DataSet was loaded".  You may already know that--just making sure.

Comment: I knew this: "Because the row for new records is in the Rows collection, use the IsNewRow property to determine whether a row is the row for new records or is a populated row. A row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins." Taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow(v=vs.110).aspx -- apparently I have to re-read that stuff :) thanks anyways!

Comment: Yup, sorry PID, I was pointing it out to the OP, not to you, who obviously knew.  :-)

Comment: Ah, well :) Sorry for mis-reading you. My door is always open to nice people teaching me new things and helping me getting better :)

Answer (score 0):

You got `IsNewRow` wrong. It is true only for the row that allows the user to insert new data. A bound row contains database data, meaning that it is not new data but persisted data.

What you need to avoid a `NullReferenceException` is check the row type. Probably the header row is messing things up...

See if this helps: [RowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through like this for example:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     decimal temp;
     if(!row.IsNewRow && decimal.TryParse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out temp))
        yearSalary += temp;
}
```